# How to copy dependency jars in a gradle task to a directory, fully deleting all files of old one

Tags: gradle

For my integration test automation with Gradle I need to copy the library directory into the directory where my Dockerfile resides to generate the docker image. I am doing this:

```
task copyRuntimeLibsToLocal(type: Copy) {
    group = 'docker'
    dependsOn   'build'
    from (configurations.compileOnly){
        exclude 'ehcache*.jar'
    }
    into "/MYDOCKERDIR/dependenciesLibraryDir"
}
```

But how can I make sure that old jars in dependenciesLibrary are deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `type: Sync` instead of `type: Copy`. They are the same except that `Sync` additionally removes files that are present in the destination directory and are not copied.